# Load different HTML into same #Content DIV on clicking different buttons

Tags: jquery, html

I have a menu with several options, I would like to know how to load different HTML into the same `div` (called `#content`) depending on the buttons you press of the menu.

I have this code for the menu:

```
<div id="mainmenu">
<ul id="menu">
<li><a href="#">Accueil</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Qui suis-je?</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Biographie</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Discographie</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Porfolio</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

What do I need to do to send, for example, "index.html" into `div#content` when I press in the menu the option "Accueil"?

Answer (score 4):

Using `jQuery ajax` you can do it

**HTML**

```
<div id="mainmenu">
    <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="index.php">Accueil</a></li>
       <li><a href="the url you want to load for this menu">Qui suis-je?</a>
    <ul>
</div>​
```

**JAVASCRIPT(jQuery)**

```
​​$(function(){
    $('#menu li a').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var page_url=$(this).prop('href');
        $('#content').load(page_url);
    });
});
```

[**jQuery load**](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [jQuery](http://jquery.com), it makes stuff like this easy:

Then you can do this:

```
$('#content>div').load('index.html');
```

You can either put this in `onclick` on some button, or in other place in your `javascript` code...